# Scrapy: Issues in dealing with Abbr tag in Xpath

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm a bit new to Scrapy, and I'm having an issue dealing with (or rather, I think the issue is in dealing with) the abbr tag, however I'm not 100% certain.

I'm trying to get the abbr title out of the following html:

```
<div class="meta">
        Post by: <a href="index.php?members/18862/" class="username" dir="auto">Eric</a>,
        <abbr title="Feb 13, 2016 at 1:45 PM" class="DateTime" data-time="1455389113" data-diff="3240" data-datestring="Feb 13, 2016" data-timestring="1:45 PM">54 minutes ago</abbr>
        in forum: <a href="index.php?forums/154/">Forum Games</a>
    </div>
```

The issue I'm dealing here is when I use the following code for my spider:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//h3[@class="title"]'):
        item = ZqItem()
        item['user'] = sel.xpath('../../div[@class="meta"]/a[@class="username"]/text()').extract()
        item['date'] = sel.xpath('../../div[@class="meta"]/abbr[@class="DateTime"]/@title').extract()

        yield item
```

I can't get the date (scrapy returns 'date': [], in powershell). However, user is returned fine leaving me to think that it might be the abbr tag giving me an issue.

Additionally, I tried using my code on a different but similar piece of html, that has span in place of abbr, and it works (successfully returns title). (keep in mind, though, that there are some other differences in the html- perhaps this is the cause of the issue?)

```
<div class="meta">
        Post by: <a href="index.php?members/18862/" class="username" dir="auto">Eric</a>,
        <span class="DateTime" title="Feb 4, 2016 at 9:37 AM">Feb 4, 2016</span>
        in forum: <a href="index.php?forums/8/">General</a>
    </div>
```

With the spider as:

```
def parse(self, response):
for sel in response.xpath('//h3[@class="title"]'):
    item = ZqItem()
    item['user'] = sel.xpath('../../div[@class="meta"]/a[@class="username"]/text()').extract()
    item['date'] = sel.xpath('../../div[@class="meta"]/span[@class="DateTime"]/@title').extract()

    yield item
```

Can anyone spread some light on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: If your Python code mentions `<h3>` then your sample HTML should contain `<h3>`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that the code isn't the full HTML, just the magnified part I'm dealing with to get the abbr tag.

Comment: That's a good thing. Still the sample Python code and the sample HTML code should be aligned, since the XPath references are relative, which makes context important.

Comment: Can you please provide the URL ?

Comment: As per the question, my guess is that the date is generated dynamically when the page loads using JavaScript. If this is the case, it can't be crawled through scrapy. Please provide the url to be sure if it can be crawled or not.

Comment: Here's the page: http://forums.vainglorygame.com/index.php?search/814444/

It should be noted that when posts are within a week old, the abbr tag is used, and after they are a week old, they switch to the span tag.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume the date is not generated dynamically using javascript.
You could do that:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="meta"]/a[@class="username"]'):

        date = sel.xpath('../span[@class="DateTime"]/@title').extract()
        date += sel.xpath('../abbr[@class="DateTime"]/@title').extract()

        item = ZqItem()
        item['user'] = sel.xpath('./text()').extract()
        item['date'] = date

        yield item
```